# how to get data in correct order in igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have diagram that need to be represented in correct order as in dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
col1 = c("A1",   "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "A",   "B",   "C",  "D", "E"),
col2 = c("ABC", "ABC", "B1", "B1", "B1", "A1",  "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1"))
```

In dataset both `col1` and `col2` first 5 elements are used to represent hierarchy.

```
library(igraph) 

abc <- union(df$col2, df$col1)
df <- df[c('col2', 'col1')]
names(df) <- c('from', 'to')
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = abc)
plot(g,vertex.size=2, vertex.label.dist=0.5, vertex.color="cyan", 
 edge.arrow.size=0.5, layout=layout.reingold.tilford(g))
```

And with this code I get this diagram

A and B should be in  front of diagram and should read A, B, C, D, E

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `igraph` plots both edges and vertices "in order". Therefore, I think you can reorder your vertices:

`abc <- abc[order(abc)]`

...and then your existing code should work.

[image: Re-ordered graph]

Comment: could also use `abc <- sort(union(df$col2, df$col1))`